# Help identifying a Bianchi track frame

Tags: frames, fixed-gear, campagnolo

I've been trying to identify this Bianchi track frame - any help would be appreciated! Closest I've come is Eco Pista from early 80s, but I'm absolutely no expert on the matter.

The numbers on the BB shell, as far as I can read are: H817 stamped on right, BG in centre, 56 575 stamped on left.

Dropouts are Campagnolo.

I resprayed frame from it's original terrible condition (was Bianchi green with Bianchi decals, not certain though if these were original or not), and put on drilled forks (forks I got with the frame were chrome and not drilled).

[image: Frame Geometry]
[image: BB Shell Frame Number]

Comment: I would've loved to see this frame before respray, the 'terrible condition' as you call it, I call 'Patina' and find very attractive.

Comment: That front fork appears bent backward at the crown.  It probably rides okay but steers like a sick whale and brakes like the Marx Brothers.  Has it been in a frontal collision ?

Comment: I've seen forks designed to be at this angle, so unless there's deformation near the crown or a difference between the fork blades, I wouldn't worry about it. (Except for toe-overlap issues)